# About the the use of Nginx

Tags: nginx

I was learning nginx and as I found out that it is a load balancer helping to handle a loads of requests to a server. The question I wanted to ask is that as I also found out, nginx is best to be used when one server gets overloaded and we need to add up one more server. So, is it true that nginx is best to used ONLY when one server cannot handle the number of requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it looks like Nginx should be added only when you need to load balance between multiple servers, and IMO this decision is correct as sometimes it is good to avoid increasing the entropy if you can't manage it.

But apart from being a load balancer, Nginx is also widely used for:

- Reverse proxy for multiple services [virtual hosts] (load balancing isn't mandatory)
- Content caching (to avoid request hitting upstream servers everytime)
- SSL termination
- API Gateway (for security, rate limiting and routing)
- Sometimes, also as a web server

so even if you aren't load-balancing you can get benefit from facilities provided by nginx like content caching, SSL termination, rate limiting, etc.
Later when need arises you can easily add more machines in the upstream to start load balancing.

Comment: hi)), thank you for your kind comments, just one question. If you were creating project having one server, would you use nginx? if yes, what exact features of it would be applicable to you.

Comment: If I have SSL certificates for HTTPS then I'll use nginx for handling SSL termination (handling traffic over HTTPS) although many application server support it like apache (generally for PHP), gunicorn (python), etc and second great use-case is content caching because I want to avoid requests to be processed by application everytime if it can be served with nginx itself without proxying to application server as this will be a performace booster for me (This can also be avoided if you don't have much traffic to bother about).